Passing parametes to a twig template
I am creating a custom module to create a controller that runs every time we access a certain route. I have university entities created and a view to represent them in a list. When I click on one I want it to take me to the university page, so I want to create a menu and put a certain image (saved in a field of the university entity). The problem is that it creates everything necessary but the image does not appear, I also put control logs but they do not appear either.
The idea is have a university-menu twig template to create the menu, and invoque it in views which I need.
I try to access the url mysite/universidad/universidad-de-vigo and I don't get any log. But if I access mysite/university/test yes.
I am attaching the configuration files.

File university_controller.info.yml
name: 'University Controller'
type: module
description: 'Proporciona un controlador para mostrar detalles de la universidad.'
core_version_requirement: '^9.4 || ^10'
package: Custom
dependencies:
  - drupal:node

File university_controller.routing.yml
university_controller.content:
  path: '/universidad/{university_name}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\university_controller\Controller\UniversityController::content'
    _title: 'Detalles de la Universidad'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'




university_controller.test:
  path: 'universidad/test'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\university_controller\Controller\UniversityController::test'
    _title: 'Prueba de Controlador'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

File UniversityController.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\university_controller\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class UniversityController extends ControllerBase {

  public function content($university_name) {
    // Depuración al inicio del método
    \Drupal::logger('university_controller')->notice('Método content() llamado con el nombre: @nombre', ['@nombre' => $university_name]);

    // Convertir el nombre de la universidad de la URL a un formato que coincida con el título del nodo
    $university_name = str_replace('-', ' ', $university_name);
    \Drupal::logger('university_controller')->notice('Buscando universidad con nombre: @nombre', ['@nombre' => $university_name]);

    // Buscar el nodo de la universidad por el nombre
    $query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
    $nids = $query
      ->condition('type', 'universidad')
      ->condition('title', $university_name)
      ->execute();

    if (empty($nids)) {
      \Drupal::logger('university_controller')->error('No se encontró el nodo con nombre @nombre', ['@nombre' => $university_name]);
      return [
        '#markup' => $this->t('No se encontró la universidad con el nombre @nombre', ['@nombre' => $university_name]),
      ];
    }

    $nid = reset($nids);
    \Drupal::logger('university_controller')->notice('Nodo encontrado con ID: @id', ['@id' => $nid]);

    $university = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);

    // Verificar si el nodo se cargó correctamente
    if (!$university) {
      \Drupal::logger('university_controller')->error('Error al cargar el nodo con ID @id', ['@id' => $nid]);
      return [
        '#markup' => $this->t('Error al cargar la universidad con el ID @id', ['@id' => $nid]),
      ];
    }

    \Drupal::logger('university_controller')->notice('Nodo cargado correctamente. ID: @id', ['@id' => $nid]);

    // Obtener la URL del logo
    if ($university->hasField('field_logo') && !$university->get('field_logo')->isEmpty()) {
      $logo_uri = $university->get('field_logo')->entity->getFileUri();
      $logo_url = file_create_url($logo_uri);
      \Drupal::logger('university_controller')->notice('Logo URL: @url', ['@url' => $logo_url]);
    } else {
      $logo_url = ''; // URL del logo por defecto
      \Drupal::logger('university_controller')->notice('No se encontró el logo para la universidad con nombre @nombre', ['@nombre' => $university_name]);
    }

    return [
      '#theme' => 'page',
      '#university_logo' => $logo_url,
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => [
          'b5subtheme/global-styling',
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }

  public function test() {
    \Drupal::logger('university_controller')->notice('Ruta de prueba llamada correctamente.');
    return [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Controlador de prueba llamado correctamente.'),
    ];
  }
}

The first log is no longer printed, which is what surprises me.
To clarify. I have a subtheme created from bootstrap5. There I have the twig template for the menu and the twig template to display a degree (when I view a degree I also want the university menu to be maintained). The list of universities is displayed through a view that was created from the Drupal graphical interface.
Right now when I show a degree, the menu that appears is configured statically, it does not change depending on the university where said degree is taken. What I want is that, when I access the page /universidad/university_name, I get information about the university with the corresponding menu, and that when I access universidad/university_name/career_name I get information about the career (I already have the template configured to show the information) but with the menu of the corresponding university.

That you don't see log entries every time you visit the URL might be caching. This is an issue with debugging Drupal, but your problem is that you assume the page variable you set in the controller ends up in page template Drupal builds. The controller builds it's own template and using the same as the Drupal page template can be quite confusing if not causing completely unpredictable results. So use a custom template in a custom controller and control the page variables in hook_preprocess_page().

You can’t ignore Drupal cache contexts when creating content programmatically.

Can you explain a little more pls?

I added some information to the post

The question topic is passing a parameter to a twig template (which doesn't belong to the controller in this case). Drupal cache contexts for a menu is a completely different topic and is not connected to this one because a page template doesn't need a cache context when accessing the current route.

Pass the template parameters in a preprocess hook:
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() !== 'university_controller.content') {
    return;
  }
  $university_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('university_name');
  ...
  $variables['university_logo'] = $logo_url;
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'b5subtheme/global-styling';
}

You have access to the same route parameters as the controller.
